# MYSQL with sum distinct and if

Tags: mysql, if-statement, sum, distinct

I have three tables. I name it here first, second and third table.

Relationship first and second table: One to many
Relationship second and third table: One to many

I need to count based on second table so I use this syntax:

`COUNT(DISTINCT second.id_panel, IF(ind_presentation=1,1,NULL))`

This count statement running well and produce correct result.

I also need to do distinct and using IF statement but for SUM statement. This is the original statement:
`SUM(IF(ind_presentation=2,second.mark,NULL))`

but i still need to add distinct in the statement

`SUM(DISTINCT second.id_panel, IF(ind_presentation=2,second.mark,NULL))`

This statement throw an error. Is there any ways I can use distinct and IF in the same statement for SUM?

If I join first and second table only, there is no need to do distinct, but I have to join the third table to SUM other marks in that table.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: *This statement throw an error.* Of course. You have double error. 1) SUM(DISTINCT) is not supported. 2) SUM() cannot receive two arguments. *Is there any ways I can use distinct and IF in the same statement for SUM?* Apply DISTINCT in CTE/subquery then SUM() in outer query.